# How to split dataframe using certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, split

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Sensor,Value,LocationLat,LocationLong,TimeStamp,Measurement
pm25,20.0,45.6568,25.5917,1611506922000,µg/m3
pm10,25.0,45.670103,25.617966,1611506922000,µg/m3
pm1,20.0,45.670103,25.617966,1611506922000,µg/m3
pm1,15.0,45.653509,25.56612,1611506908000,µg/m3
```

I want to split the sensors present in the Sensor column into pm25, pm10 and pm1 columns. How could I split the dataframe so that I have as columns pm25, pm10 and pm1 and take as value the corresponding values from the Value column?

Also I would need to group the data by TimeStamp after doing the split of sensors.

So that for timestamp `1611506922000` I could have the sensors values in the same row.

For splitting the Sensors into pm2.5, pm1 and pm10 columns, I tried:

```
for sensor_name in df['Sensor'].unique():
    df[sensor_name] = df['Value'][df['Sensor'] == sensor_name]
```

But this gives me only one value in a sensor column and the others are empty.

The final df should look like this:

```
pm25,pm10,pm1,Value,LocationLat,LocationLong,TimeStamp,Measurement
20.0,25.0,20.0,45.6568,25.5917,1611506922000,µg/m3
NaN,NaN,15.0,45.653509,25.56612,1611506908000,µg/m3
```

the values being grouped by the same timestamp, in the same row.

Comment: About the timestamp grouping. How do you want to group them? Summing the values? Could you please provide and example of the output?

Comment: @AndreaIerardi I have edited the question with the final structure of how the grouping should look like

Answer (score 0):

I belive something like this will be what you are after:

```
pivoted_df=stack_df.pivot(index=["LocationLat","LocationLong","TimeStamp","Measurement"],columns="Sensor",values="Value")
```